# Installing socket.io returns (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, npm

When running command `sudo npm install socket.io` I get following output.

```
> ws@0.4.31 install /Users/xafar/Documents/projects/node/chat/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished

> ws@0.4.31 install /Users/xafar/Documents/projects/node/chat/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
socket.io@1.2.0 node_modules/socket.io
├── debug@0.7.4
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.2 (isarray@0.0.1, component-emitter@1.1.2, benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── engine.io@1.4.2 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.1.0, ws@0.4.31)
└── socket.io-client@1.2.0 (to-array@0.1.3, indexof@0.0.1, component-bind@1.0.0, object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, has-binary@0.1.5, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.4.2)
```

I am wondering because generally when I run above command `npm install something` then http GET requests  are sent to repository to download those dependencies. **Why I am not getting the same output here?** If this is an error then **how can I resolve this?**

Answer (score 0):

what you see is the C++ compilation.
some npm modules got C++ which gets compiled during the module installation.

Comment: no errors. if you had an error you would see it and it would not print that the module was installed with its sub modules.

Comment: There is a build error atleast thats how I can see it.

Comment: did you even check node_modules/socket.io that the dir exists? if so, compilation worked, otherwise npm would have deleted that module folder.